# Windows Service Not connecting to SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, service

I have a simple windows service that we have used for years. We developed it in-house, but no one has touched it for years. It updates a couple tables in a SQL database located on the same server. I installed it on a virtual server, and it appears to be running, but is not updating the SQL database.

I believe it connects to the database using an Alias set up in CLICONFG. It is set using a Named Pipes connection pointing to the local SQL EXPRESS database.

It is running properly on a server with a default instance of SQL EXPRESS installed. The only difference I can find is this current server has a Named Instance (.\SQLEXPRESS). However, I have had it running successfully on other servers with a Named instance rather than a default instance, but I can't seem to get this one to work.

I have searched and searched and have been unable to figure out what is wrong.
I've checked for possible permissions issues in SQL, and everything seems to be in order with the login I have chosen for the service.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it using an ODBC connection at all?

Comment: How does it get it's connection string to talk to SQL?  A config file, is it hardcoded in the service itself, or it could be an argument passed in.  Without knowing how it talks to SQL that could be a problem.  Also check your event logs as it could be throwing errors left and right even if it is running.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I believe the connection is hard-coded into the service. We use a config file for other settings, but the connection is not included in that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know for sure how it connects to SQL. The service is used in conjunction with a classic ASP/ASP.net web application. The web program uses two connection strings: one in the registry and a web.config file.  The web app is connecting to the database just fine for both the classic ASP and the .Net pages. Also, the server has a Named Pipes Alias set up (it could be the hard-coded connection references the alias because we use the same alias for every server we install it to).

Comment: I found out some information on how it connects to the database, can anyone provide any more insight? Thanks!!

Comment: FYI - I updated my original question to include the new information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I figured it out!

Turns out it was connecting to SQL through a Named Pipes Connection setup in cliconfg.

I already had a Named Pipes Connection setup with our standard alias....and the pipe specifying the SQL Named Instance....that wasn't working for this server.

The service was expecting a default instance. The service had worked properly before w/a Named Instance w/out modifying our standard Named Pipes configuration, but that was a 32-bit windows server. This time, on a 64-bit windows server, it wasn't working.

So....

I used ProcMon to determine what it was looking for...then added a second Named Pipes connection named "(local)" instead of our standard alias. I set the pipe up exactly the same as our other connection. I left our standard Named Pipes Connection there as well with our standard alias.

Rebooted and it worked!